# How to know 2 day old puppies are getting enough milk?

Tags: dogs

So my dog, a 5 year old German Shepherd, had 8 puppies 2 days ago. She delivered normally and, from the little that I know, they all seemed healthy. They were crying right after birth, and all.of them manoeuvred their way to suck milk.
But since then (48hrs) we have noticed that the puppies sleeping a bit too much compared to their first day. We felt like something was wrong so we checked our dog to see if nipples were producing milk properly and we found that on pressing them only the last two (near the hind legs)  released very little milk, and the rest released nothing. Also we saw in some other dogs the milk sacs are usually very swollen after birth but for my dog only the last two are swollen and the rest are very little if not completely flat. 
Is this normal for German shepherds?  And if not then should we consider dog formula milk for the puppies? Also is the formula milk safe and healthy for the pups?
How do we tell if the puppies are healthy and feeding properly?

Honestly I'm really worried and would appreciate your inputs!!

P.S.: my vet is out of town for Easter holidays and won't be back for the next four days so yeah really need your advice for now!